# Why won't my website scroll when a small div's position is set to fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and have a side element that has buttons that I want to stay in place when a user scrolls down, but when I set the position to fixed, I lose the ability to scroll

[absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG3Ir.png)
   [Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phagg.png)
            `#sidebar {
        font-size: 20px;
        background: #168AE9;
        position: absolute;
        width: 230px;
        height: 500px;
        line-height: 2;
        top: 77px;
        left: 0%;
        text-align: center;`

Comment: Please give us the source code and show us screenshots. Make sure to be more detailed.

Comment: I imagine it would be because the other elements outside of the fixed element don't exceed the browser viewport.
The `fixed` element automatically stops behaving as a scrollable element by default.

Comment: Is there is away to get around it

Comment: Can you include your html? It's hard to see what could be going wrong without that included.